# How can I iterate through the hover pictures and click on every profile under the them?

Tags: java, selenium, hover

I'm on the https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/hovers .
I would like to create a for loop, that moves the mouse cursor to the pictures, clicks on the profile links, then navigates back to the pictures and clicks on the next pictures, etc.

```
private final By images = By.xpath("//*[@class=\"figure\"]"); 
private final By profileLinks = By.xpath(".//div/a"); // relative xpath    
public void clickAllProfiles() 
{
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        List<WebElement> pictures = driver.findElements(images);   
        for (WebElement pic : pictures)     
        {
            actions.moveToElement(pic)
                    .click(driver.findElement(profileLinks))
                    .build()
                    .perform();
            driver.navigate().back();
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }
}
```

I don't know why, but my test automation does not click on the links under the pictures, and navigates back to the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, this is working.

```
    List<WebElement> pictures = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//img[@alt='User Avatar']"));
    
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    int i = 1;
    for (WebElement pic : pictures) {
        actions.moveToElement(pic).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@href='/users/" + i + "']"))).perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.navigate().back();
        i++;
    }
```